# fs.writeFile creating empty files (node.js)

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm trying to write a scraping script with node.js, cheerio and puppeteer.

The issue I'm having at the moment is trying to get the `writeFile()` function to work correctly.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const $ = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');
const url = 'https://www.made-up-url.com/';

puppeteer
    .launch()
    .then(function(browser) {
        return browser.newPage();
    })
    .then(function(page) {
        return page.goto(url).then(function() {
            return page.content();
        });
    })
    .then(function(html) {
        let scrapedTitle = $('h1', html).each(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        });
        let scrapedDesc = $('#something-else > div > p', html).each(function() {
            return $(this).text();
        });

        // Both console logs are outputted as strings, as expected
        console.log(scrapedTitle[0].children[0].data); // "Some title"
        console.log(scrapedDesc[0].children[0].data); // "The description is like this."

        fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(scrapedTitle[0].children[0].data), 'utf8', function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }
            console.log("The data has been scraped and saved successfully! View it at './data.json'");
        });

        process.exit();
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit();
    });
```

`writeFile()` has worked in the past with something like this `fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(html), 'utf8', function(err) {`, but now this appears to not be working either. When I run this script the file is created, as expected, but it is always empty, even when the two `console.log()` shows there should be valid strings to write. There are no errors. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the line below, The `process.exit();` is closing the process before the file write operation:

```
fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(scrapedTitle[0].children[0].data), 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("The data has been scraped and saved successfully! View it at './data.json'");
});

process.exit();
```

You can change it to something like this so that the file write operation completes before you close it:

```
fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(scrapedTitle[0].children[0].data), 'utf8', function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
        process.exit();        
    }
    console.log("The data has been scraped and saved successfully! View it at './data.json'");
    process.exit();
});
```